# Return back to my home screen after login a webpage

Tags: android

My application needs to return back to my home screen after I login on a web page successfully, but my code doesn't work. Does anyone knows what's the problem? I have been thinking how to do this all day but I cannot figure it out. Thanks in advance!!!

```
package com.example.loginapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class LogInPage extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

              //Allow the title bar to show loading progress.
              requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

              WebView webview = new WebView(this);

              setContentView(webview);

              webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

              webview.loadUrl("http://myLogInPage.com");

              webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
              public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
               // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
               // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                  setProgress(progress * 100);
          }
       });

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

//When start to load page, show URL in activity's title bar 
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,Bitmap favicon) {
         setTitle(url);
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {


  CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

  // Get the cookie from cookie jar.
  String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        if (cookie == null) {
             return;
        }

        String[] pairs = cookie.split(";");

        for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; ++i) {

          String[] parts = pairs[i].split("=", 2);
          // If token is found, return it to the calling activity.

          if (parts.length == 2 && parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("oauth_token")) {

            Intent result = new Intent();

            result.putExtra("token", parts[1]);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, result);

            String token = result.getStringExtra("token");
            if (token != null) {

                //return back to my home screen
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            finish();
         }
      }  
  }

});
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the token String isn't null? Are you absolutely positive that the if statement is entered?

Comment: Either token or cookie is `null`

Comment: @TimKranen Because I was thinking if I could be able to log in the web page successfully, then the token String won't be null. I want to return back to my home screen once I login.

Comment: @TimKranen Or are you saying the way I am trying to get the token String is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

put the finish in else statment to work fine.

```
 if (token != null) {

                    //return back to my home screen
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{

                finish();
                }
```